# MySQL same value once

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I speak a little English.

```
CREATE TABLE `links` (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
category_id INT NOT NULL, -- 1: Facebook, 2: Twitter, ...
url VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
state TINYINT(1) NOT NULL -- boolean
);

INSERT INTO `links` ( `id`, `category_id`, `url`, `state` ) VALUES
( 1, 1, 'cnn', 1 ), -- Facebook
( 2, 2, 'cnn', 1 ), -- Twitter
( 3, 1, 'bbc', 1 ), -- Facebook
( 4, 2, 'bbc', 1 ), -- Twitter
( 5, 1, 'cnn', 1 ), -- It's wrong. This is same as id=1
( 6, 1, 'cnn', 1 ), -- It's wrong. This is same as id=1 (and id=5)
( 7, 1, 'abc', 0 ); -- It's wrong. This is state!=1.
```

I would like show this after MySQL SELECT...

```
category_id | count
1             2
2             2
```

This is:

```
SELECT * FROM `links` ???
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for the GROUP BY clause of sql.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT category_id, COUNT(DISTINCT url) AS count
FROM links
WHERE state = 1
GROUP BY category_id
```

Comment: Close, but it reads like the OP wants to have the last entries "wrong" filtered out.

Comment: Not good. It's 5 (Facebook) and 2 (Twitter), not 2 (FB) and 2 (T).

Comment: I have included that check in where clause now.

Answer (score 0):

You need distinct count and group by together

```
select 
category_id,
count(distinct url) as `count` 
from links where state = 1 group by category_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid inserting 5 and 6, add this to the table:

```
UNIQUE(`category_id`, `url`)
```

If you don't want to insert state=0, then do not specify it.  Add `DEFAULT '1'` to the declaration of `state` and remove that column from the INSERTs.

For that matter, you may as well remove `id` and 1..7 from the INSERTs, since that is what AUTO_INCREMENT is all about.